# Finding the probability of occurrence N people having the same birthday

Tags: c, arrays, random

I have a homework with regards to finding the number of occurrences where N people have the same birthdays. I have to write a function findSameBirthday that takes as argument the birthdays array
and the value K. The function returns `true` if there is an occurrence of K similar
birthdays within the N elements. I have generated an array called `birthdays`, which is filled with numbers from 0 to 364. However, when I run my code, I do not seem to get an output. Where have I gone wrong?

My idea to check for the same birthdays in an array is:

1. From `birthdays[0]`, I will check it with `birthdays[1]`, `birthdays[2]`, `birthdays[3]`, ..., `birthdays[999]`.
2. From `birthdays[1]`, I will check it with `birthdays[2]`, ... , `birthdays[999]`.
3. For each successful find, I will increase `hit` by 1.
4. Hence, as long as `hit` is 1 or more, I will return `true`, else I will return `false` from the function `findSameBirthday`.

This is my code; it's also here: http://codepad.org/JFLvUn4w

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdbool.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>
  #include <time.h>
  #define SEED time(0)
  #define MAX 1000

  void fillBirthdays(int birthdays[], int N);
  bool findSameBirthday(int birthdays[], int k);

  int main(void)
  {
      int birthdays[MAX]={0};
      int hits=0, k=0, N=0;

      scanf("%d", &N);
      srand((unsigned int) SEED);
      fillBirthdays(birthdays, N);
      findSameBirthday(birthdays, k);
      printf("%d", hits);

      return 0;
  }

  /*  
      fillBirthdays fills N birthdays into the array birthdays
      by using a table-lookup method.  The indices 0 to 364
      represent the different birthdays, and the value of 
      birthdays[k] is the number of people within the group of N
      having the same birthday k.

  Precondition: none.
   */
  void fillBirthdays(int birthdays[], int N)
  {
      int i=0;

      for(i=0;i<N;i++)
      {
          birthdays[i]=rand()%365;
      }

      return;
  }

  /*  
      findSameBirthday returns true if there are k (or more)
      same birthdays, and false otherwise.

  Precondition: none.
   */
  bool findSameBirthday(int birthdays[], int k)
  {
      int N=0, i=0, j=0, hits=0;
      bool samebirthday=true;

      for(i=0;i<N;i++)
      {
          for(j=1;j<N;j++)
          {
              if(birthdays[i]==birthdays[j])
                  hits=hits+1;
          }
      }
      if(hits>0)
          return samebirthday;
      else
          return false;
  }
```

Comment: `findSameBirthday(birthdays, k);` k is 0 here. In `findSameBirthday`, you never use `k`, and `N` is 0 in `for(i=0;i<N;i++)`.

Comment: Can you just traverse the birthdays array once and create an array of ints of length 365 that indicates how many people have the birthday specified by the array index? Then you can just traverse this new array looking for a value equal to 'k'.

Comment: Your code does have several issues. For example: you declare a variable `int hits` in `main`, but you never use it. That does probably lead to a program where you have no idea what it does and why. Another example: the inner loop you have should probably not start from `int j = 1`, but from `int j = i+1`...

Comment: Oh wow. Thank you for helping me paste the code here. May I know how do you do it? I found it challenging to paste my entire code with the right formatting (they became a lump). Please allow me some time to digest the comments. Thank you once again. :)

Comment: `findSameBirthday` will always return false. Also,modifying a local variable from a function will not change the value of the variable with a same name  in another function

Comment: @JohnnyMopp: Oh. Oops. I think I overlooked that. Hmm.. I think I am a little confused. I have to find the number of people with the same birthdays. The number of people, N, comes from the main program, but I don't know why the skeletal code given to me is written as bool(findSameBirthday(..., int k).

Comment: @Theolodis: Oh ya. Thank you for the part on j=i+1. I missed that out. >< Sorry. I tried to use hits in main by doing a printf("%d", hits) to see the number of occurrences of the people who have the same birthday.

Comment: After looking through the quotes, I have a feeling that I should put the search for the same birthdays in the fillBirthdays function. May I know if I am correct to say this? Then from the fillBirthdays function, I will have k, which is the number of hits, so I can do: "If k>1, then there are people with the same birthdays, else, return false."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should fix your `findSameBirthday` function:

```
/* findSameBirthday returns true if there are k (or more)
   same birthdays, and false otherwise.

   Precondition: none. */
bool findSameBirthday(int birthdays[], int k)
{
    int hits = 0;

    /* We don't know how big the array is, but that's ok,
       loop to max but break out early if needed. 
       birthdays array is 0 initialized so will be filled 
       with 0's where no data is present. */
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)  
    {
        if (!birthdays[i]) {break;}     // We have reached the end of the array, break out
                                         // And check hit count
        for (int j = i+1; j < MAX; j++)  // Start from i+1 so there is no overlap
        {
            if (!birthdays[j]) {break;} // We have reached the end of the array, break out 
                                        // And check next number
            if (birthdays[i] == birthdays[j])
                {hits++;}
        }
    }
    return hits >= k; // >= means equal or more
}
```

You could of course pass `N` into the function too. You can then remove the checks and the breaks in the loops, but I wanted to match your function declaration.

```
/* findSameBirthday returns true if there are k (or more)
   same birthdays, and false otherwise.

   Precondition: none. */
bool findSameBirthday(int birthdays[], int N, int k)
{
    int hits = 0;
    
    /* We don't know how big the array is, but that's ok,
       loop to max but break out early if needed. 
       birthdays array is 0 initialized so will be filled 
       with 0's where no data is present. */
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)  
    {
        for (int j = i+1; j < n; j++)  // Start from i+1 so there is no overlap
        {
            if (birthdays[i] == birthdays[j])
                {hits++;}
        }
    }
    return hits >= k; // >= means equal or more
}
```

You understand that with an input like this:

```
int birthdays[] = {5, 5, 2, 7, 5, 9, 5};
```

The result with this algorithm will be `sum(0 to n-1)` where `n` is the number of people who share the same birthday?
(in this case the result will be `6`).

as for why you are not getting any output, you should (currently) be seeing a `0` output [(see here)](http://ideone.com/Ub8E35). This is because you set `hits` in main to be `0` and do not modify it.

If you want it to just say that there are 'k' matching birtdays or not, you can change the end of `main()` to be:

```
//findSameBirthday(birthdays, k);
printf("%s", findSameBirthday(birthdays, k)?
       "No. of matching Birthdays hits threshold":
       "No. of matching Birthdays does not hit threshold"
);
```

If you want to output the number of `hits`:

- Change function prototype of `findSameBirthday` to `int findSameBirthday(...)`
- Return `hits` from `findSameBirthday()`
- In main:

  ```
  hits = findSameBirthday(birthdays, k);
  printf("Number of matching birthdays found: %d", hits);
  ```

This will output the number of hits.

Comment: Thank you for your codes. :) I did not learn break statement in my C course but I can roughly recall its function from another introductory course on C. "break" allows us to break out entirely from a while/for loop if a condition is not satisfied right?

Comment: If I were to loop it to N, which is a number a user has to input, I will have to pull the for statements (which check for the same birthdays) to the fillBirthday function? Am I right to say this?

Comment: Oh dear. I can't seem to use the "@" function. The above 2 comments are for Baldrickk. Sorry.

Comment: This answer adds a feature (making the size of the array configurable) which we don't need. This answer contains an important bug fix `j = i+1` but doesn't explain it. Also, the original problem is "when I run my code, I do not seem to get an output" - does this answer fix it? What caused it?

Comment: @galaxy_twirl yes, `break` will stop loop execution (program flow continues from the end of the loop) `continue` will jump into the next loop imediately.   Yes, you can pass N into the function and then loop to that - I'll add it to the answer

Comment: @anatolyg: I think I know why I need to put j=i+1 instead of j=1. This is because, when the j loops restarts after i increases to 1, in which I will be checking birthdays[1] == birthdays[1] which will be erroneous. I should be checking birthdays[1] == birthdays[2], etc. Hence, count of j must be tagged to the value of i. As for the output, I think it may have to do with my printf statements, as printf are used to make the program output sth on the screen.

Comment: @anatolyg I didn't make it configurable, I just made it so that it would loop within bounds _and_ the data without the size being passed in (as the function prototype was in the question). I have now added code to show the function with passing the size in.  I explained `j=i+1` in the comments.  I have also now added in notes on the output.